# How to install GEOS with native Ruby bindings?

Tags: ruby, geometry, geospatial, postgis, geos

GEOS is a C++ port of the Java Topology Suite. It enables geometry and geospatial processing, and is the library beneath PostgreSQL's PostGIS. I want to work with it directly in Ruby, not in PostGIS, and I know that there are native Ruby bindings, but the documentation online is sparse, and installation is buggy. How do I install GEOS with the Ruby bindings enabled?

Comment: I know there is a gem called `ffi-geos`, but I asked this question so I could answer it with a reliable process for installing from source with the native bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. Compile and Install Swig

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install swig
```

**Mac OS X**

Download and unpack the [swig source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swig/files/swig/). In the unpacked directory:

```
./configure --without-pcre
make && sudo make install
```

(Or use `brew install`.)

### 2. Download and Configure GEOS

Download and unpack the [GEOS source code](http://download.osgeo.org/geos/). In the unpacked directory:

```
./configure --enable-ruby
```

Look for status lines showing `Swig: true` and `Ruby bindings: true`.

### 3. Compile and install GEOS

Try to compile and install:

```
make && sudo make install
```

(If `make` ends with the error `library not found for -llibruby.2.0.0.dylib`, this is due to a bug in GEOS (currently version 3.4.2). Run the following command to fix your `configure` file:

```
sed -i -e 's/RUBY_SO_NAME=.*/RUBY_SO_NAME=ruby/' configure
```

Then go back to **Step 2**.)

### 4. Set Up Linking

You will need to make sure the library is correctly linked before using `require 'geos'` in your Ruby. The install directory appears in the output of `sudo make install`.

**Ubuntu**

The default install directory is `usr/local/lib`.

Before executing your Ruby process, add the install directory to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
```

This environment variable needs to be set whenever you run a Ruby executable, so you may want to add it to your bash profile.

**Mac OS X**

The default install directory of the `.so` file is something like `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/universal-darwin13`.

Ruby on Mac OS X requires a `.bundle` file, so we create a symbolic link to the `.so` file.

```
$ cd /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/universal-darwin13
$ sudo ln -s geos.so geos.bundle
```

This only needs to be run at install time to enable the Ruby GEOS bindings forever.

### 5. Load GEOS in Ruby

If you've linked correctly to the library, you should be able to use `require 'geos'` and see no errors.

```
$ irb
>> require 'geos'
=> true
```